# Ayleid well shareable with group/allies in Cyrodiil?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO, in Cyrodiil, I had thought that the buff gotten from Ayleid wells **in Cyrodiil** were shared by allies or group members gathered round the well during activation. But it’s been a while since this has happened in game for me. So long that maybe my memory is incorrect.

However today I found an Alyeid well and told the group, but crown said that the buff only applies to a single player. I activated it and no one was nearby.

Now I am uncertain how they work in Cyrodiil.

Searching the Internet for “ESO Ayleid well share group” surprisingly has no answer that I’ve found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember any change to then, so they should indeed provide their buff to anyone nearby. The range is rather small, so best just hug it together (not that small, but try to stay next to the inner part).

Comment: I got lucky last night and we gathered around an unused Ayleid well. Someone else activated it, and I saw my buff icon on the HUD. Accepting your answer.

Comment: Today, I was in Coldharbour, and I was grouped, and I stood near an Ayleid well while a group member activated it, and I got the buff. So the sharing is not limited to PvP areas. It’s shareable everywhere!